# Unable to press a button in IE 7

Tags: button, internet-explorer-7

I have a button in which I have defined some CSS.

```
<input type="button" class="button_enable" onclick="xxxxxxxx" >
```

This button working fine in all browsers but Not n IE7. There is not even a network request, or any effect when the button is clicked. Please help me. or else I give an alert on opening my website that **IE7 is pathetic dont use it :)**

Comment: Are you using javascript to enable/disable this button? If possible can you provide a jsfiddle for your current work?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that often happens with ie7:

1. Have you positioned an element absolutely that because of some ie7 css behaviour overlaps the button so it cannot be clicked?
2. Do you have Ie9? Within Ie9 open the developer-toolbar (F12) and activate the Ie7 mode (both document and browser mode), also, open the console (3rd tab inside the dev-toolbar).
   When you click the button, it may gives you an js-error, because internet explorer (especially old versions) are far more restrictive for errors, for instance you cannot use reserved words like "delete" as function names, or it will return an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But there are no errors in console. Yeah I have positioned it absolute. But just cant change this CSS because this shows a bad impression on other browsers.

Comment: mhm, one question: is it clickable at all in ie7? i mean, when you click it, do you see the click-effect every normal browser does?
Can you send me the url, so i can take a look?

cheers

Comment: Well cant send you the URL.. but it is not at all clickable. all of the buttons which donot apply any absolute are clickable

Comment: Well then it seems like a css-issue with another layer residing over your button i guess.